# Appending to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS in a CMake Yocto recipe which uses PACKAGECONFIG

Tags: cmake, yocto-recipe

I have a recipe which inherits from cmake_qt5

There is a

```
PACKAGECONFIG[debug] = "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug,-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"
```

When the debug variant is chosen I also need to set a preprocessor macro. I have tried this:

```
PACKAGECONFIG[debug] = "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-DSOME_DEFINE",-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"
```

But it seems that this replaces the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS in stead of appending to it.

How to add a preprocessor definition to a PACKAGECONFIG

Comment: "But it seems that this replaces the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS in stead of appending to it." - Yes, passing option `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=...` replaces the variable CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS which is set as a result of the platform detection of the `project()` call in `CMakeLists.txt`.  "How to add a preprocessor definition to a PACKAGECONFIG" - CMake doesn't provide an easy way for this. Usually, if a project want some preprocessor definition to be configurable by the user, then it adds corresponded CMake option. What kind of preprocessor definition do you want to add for QT?

Comment: In the end I indeed took the approach of adding a CMake option to CMakeLists.txt which in turn sets the preprocessor macro.